# Android Share Intent LinkedIn V3.0 Inconsistent behaviour

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedin-api

As of version 3.0, I have noticed some inconsistent behaviour when sharing something via LinkedIn using share intents. At first I thought this was a problem with my app however I have noticed the issue on other apps.

The first time I share the LinkedIn app redirects back to its homepage.

The second time onwards it works as expected - it displays the update status activity.

My question is: is this only a problem on my device or have other developers had this issue. Below is my code to share something.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "some text");
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing something awesome");
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in an update issues today (26th April 2013). I can no longer replicate it.